# Key map for ex command in emacs evil-mode

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

In emacs evil-mode, how do I bind a key sequence so that it pre-populates the evil-mode ex command line and positions the cursor? In vim, I can do this:

```
nnoremap g/r :%s//g<left><left>
```

In emacs, I tried this (and several variations):

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "g/" nil)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "g/r")
    (lambda () (interactive) (kbd ":%s/")))
```

It has no effect, and I don't see any messages after trying the keymap.

It looks like emacs used to have a useful function `evil-ex-read-command` that sent input to the evil-mode command line:

https://github.com/magnars/.emacs.d/blob/master/site-lisp/evil/evil-ex.el#L554

But that function doesn't seem to be available anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you mean to bind the key combination

1. Press and release g
2. Press and release /
3. Press and release r

your string in `kdb` should be `"g / r"`.

Emacs is not based on keystrokes as vim is, but keystrokes are just a means to execute functions. So pressing `k` in normal mode does not execute the function `k` (as in vim), but `self-insert-char`. That means that you do not bind the combination `g / r` to equal some other keystrokes, but rather to call an arbitrary function. And evil defines an [`evil-ex`](https://gitorious.org/evil/evil/source/ec2b63c2d9a238ae0ea919dd65cea1705c83be5c%3aevil-ex.el#L125) function, that does exactly what you want (Actually it's the exact function, that is called, when you press `:` in normal mode).

Untested but it should work

`(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "g / r") (lambda () (evil-ex "%s/")))`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I read the help for `(edmacro-mode)` but I'm still not clear on why I need to separate the characters by spaces. The help says that `"g/r"` would be considered a "word", and it seems to me that multi-character words are allowed.

Comment: You have to separate them, because you are using the `kbd` macro, a "precompiler". It compiles the string `"g / r"` probably to `"g/r"`, so you could replace `(kbd "g / r")` with `"g/r"`, but I, for my part, think it is much less readable, especially when you bind bindings like `"C-c g C-M-a"`, so I use `kbd` everywhere.